# How do I make a google sheets AND formula repeat in each row automaticaly

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I have a large spreadsheet that is the result of a query on another sheet. I'm trying to make a recurring (array?) formula that will repeat in every row.

The original formula is
`=AND(Index(N2:N,1,1)="FALSE", Index(H2:H,1,1)="Regular", Index(O2:O,1,1)<44801)`
This returns a True value if all 3 conditions are met. but only works on that row, so I need to copy it into each row (dragging the + marker on the cell down).

When data is added to the other sheet, the query returns more rows, I'd like not to have to do the copying of the formula to the new rows added

I tried to do this on the top row
`=Arrayformula({"name of this column"; AND(Index(N2:N,1,1)="FALSE", Index(H2:H,1,1)="Regular", Index(O2:O,1,1)<44801)})`
But I'm only getting a result in the row 2 and nothing in the following rows.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
=arrayformula((N2:N=FALSE)*(H2:H="Regular")*(O2:O<44801))
```

or

```
=arrayformula(if((N2:N=FALSE)*(H2:H="Regular")*(O2:O<44801),TRUE))
```

Comment: This might also help `=INDEX((N2:N=FALSE)*(H2:H="Regular")*(O2:O<44801))`.